# org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException mapper_parsing_exception: failed to parse field with date

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-spark

I am migrating existing applciation which using `elasticsearch-spark 7.6.0` version to latest i.e `elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12:7.15.0`. I am loading ES data with date mapping as below

```json
"my_partition_key": {
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                    "type": "date"
                }
```

However I am getting error

```
*org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: mapper_parsing_exception: failed to parse field [my_partition_key] of type [date] in document with id 'asdaszzdfdf-Ptn'. Preview of field's value: '1634601600000';org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: illegal_argument_exception: failed to parse date field [1634601600000] with format [yyyy-MM-dd];org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: date_time_parse_exception: Text '1634601600000' could not be parsed at index 0
{"index":{}}*
```

I am unable to figure out though value is in long and printing data set with `dataset.show()` displays valid date, why unable to write to ES? Is any new configuration I need to pass for date fields with latest ES? any help appreciated.

Comment: It would seem that your input data is not in the format you expect, but stored as timestamps.

Comment: Actually I am reading a partition where partition key is a date. Looks like spark is automatically treating as date based on schema. Based on my research looks like I need to explicitly convert into String to avoid storing as ephoch milliseconds.